# Console.Error.WriteLineAsync() vs Console.WriteLine, what is the difference. Why does the later throw exception?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await, json-rpc

I am trying to understand StreamJsonRpc and running an [example from here](https://github.com/AArnott/StreamJsonRpc.Sample).

I have created a [tone down example here](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/SOIssueReport-200501/tree/main/src). It contains server and client and communicates via StreamJsonRpc.

In the server, when I use **Console.WriteLine**, it throws exception. When I revert back to using **await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync()**, it runs fine.

[image: Exception is throw]

Why is that? Looks like there is something to do with await async that I am missing.

The following method works.

```cs
private static async Task RespondToRpcRequestsUsingConsoleErrorAsync(Stream stream, int clientId)
{
    await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync($"Connection request #{clientId} received. Spinning off an async Task to cater to requests.");
    var jsonRpc = JsonRpc.Attach(stream, new Server());
    await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync($"JSON-RPC listener attached to #{clientId}. Waiting for requests...");
    await jsonRpc.Completion;
    await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync($"Connection #{clientId} terminated.");
}
```

The following throws exception. You can see in the following **Console.WriteLine()** replacing **await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync()** above.

```cs
private static async Task RespondToRpcRequestsUsingConsoleAsync(Stream stream, int clientId)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection request #{clientId} received. Spinning off an async Task to cater to requests.");
    var jsonRpc = JsonRpc.Attach(stream, new Server());
    Console.WriteLine($"JSON-RPC listener attached to #{clientId}. Waiting for requests...");
    await jsonRpc.Completion;
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection #{clientId} terminated.");
}
```

I tried using **jsonRpc.Completion.Wait();** and **jsonRpc.Completion.GetAwaiter().GetResult();** as follows, but no success.

```cs
private static void RespondToRpcRequestsUsingConsoleWithWait(Stream stream, int clientId)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection request #{clientId} received. Spinning off an async Task to cater to requests.");
    var jsonRpc = JsonRpc.Attach(stream, new Server());
    Console.WriteLine($"JSON-RPC listener attached to #{clientId}. Waiting for requests...");
    jsonRpc.Completion.Wait(); // SEE HERE
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection #{clientId} terminated.");
}

private static void RespondToRpcRequestsUsingConsoleWithAwaiterAndResult(Stream stream, int clientId)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection request #{clientId} received. Spinning off an async Task to cater to requests.");
    var jsonRpc = JsonRpc.Attach(stream, new Server());
    Console.WriteLine($"JSON-RPC listener attached to #{clientId}. Waiting for requests...");
    jsonRpc.Completion.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // SEE HERE
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection #{clientId} terminated.");
}
```

#### How to run the example.

1. Just open [this](https://github.com/AvtsVivek/SOIssueReport-200501/tree/main/src) in Visual Studio, set the client as start up project and press F5.
2. With command line, cd into the client project and run it.

```
cd JsonRpcStdIoClient
dotnet run --project ./JsonRpcStdIoClient.csproj
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `async`. You are using `StandardInput`/`StandardOutput` to communicate between processes, `Console.WriteLine` writes to `StandardOutput`. So when you call it on the server it will send some random, at least from the `JsonRpc` standpoint of view, data to the communication channel which it seems that `JsonRpc` can't process, hence the result. `Console.Error` on the other hand writes to standard error stream, so it does not affect the communication channel.

As experiment remove all `Console.WriteLine` in the server and for the client add monitoring of the duplex stream:

```cs
// setup process and stdioStream

var monitoringStream = new MonitoringStream(stdioStream);
var inwr = new MemoryStream();
var outwr = new MemoryStream();
monitoringStream.DidRead += (s, e) => inwr.Write(e);  
monitoringStream.DidWrite += (s, e) => outwr.Write(e);

try
{
    await ActAsRpcClientAsync(monitoringStream);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

Console.WriteLine("----\nIn:\n");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inwr.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine("----\nOut:\n");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outwr.ToArray()));
```

Which results in something like

```
Connected. Sending request...
Received request: 3 + 5
3 + 5 = 8
----
In:

Content-Length: 35

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"result":8}
----
Out:

Content-Length: 54

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"method":"Add","params":[3,5]}
```